# Getting the gallery images from products in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Looking for a code which could potentially help me get the list of gallery images present in product in woocommerce.

Need them so i can use them in a custom single page design for woocommerce product page.

Answer (score 22):

```
<?php
$product_id = '14';
$product = new WC_product($product_id);
$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();

foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) 
    {
      // Display the image URL
      echo $Original_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );

      // Display Image instead of URL
      echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'full');

    }?>
```

Comment: You should try to explain your code, it would be helpful.

Comment: OK sure i can do it.

Comment: This is the easiest and best answer.

Answer (score 6):

The `get_gallery_image_ids()` method on the product will return an array of image IDs.

```
global $product;
$gallery_images = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();
```

Then you can use functions like `wp_get_attachment_image()` for each ID to get HTML/URLs etc.

Answer (score 6):

This is the complete function if you want all the images from the gallery, including the main image:

```
    public function getAllProducts( $request ){
    $products = new WP_Query([
        'post_type' => 'post'//,
            //'show_product_on_only_premium' => 'yes',
        ]);

    $args = array(
        'status' => 'publish',
    );
    $products = wc_get_products( $args );
    $tempArr = [];
    foreach($products as $product){
        $product_obj = json_decode($product-> __toString());
        $product_obj->img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($product_obj->image_id)[0];
        $images_ids = $product-> get_gallery_image_ids();

        $images_arr = [];
        for($i = 0, $j = count($images_ids); $i < $j;$i++ ){
            $image_query = wp_get_attachment_image_src($images_ids[$i]);
            $img = new StdClass;
            $img->src = $image_query[0];
            array_push($images_arr, $img);
        }
        $product_obj->gallery = $images_arr;
        array_push($tempArr, $product_obj);
    }
    return $tempArr;
}
```

And if you want the variations: from: https://gist.github.com/Niloys7/17b88d36c1c38844a6cf2127c15dee63

```
<?php
global $product;
$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) 
{
  //Get URL of Gallery Images - default wordpress image sizes
  echo $Original_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
  echo $full_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' )[0];
  echo $medium_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'medium' )[0];
  echo $thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail' )[0];

  //Get URL of Gallery Images - WooCommerce specific image sizes
  echo $shop_thumbnail_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'shop_thumbnail' )[0];
  echo $shop_catalog_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'shop_catalog' )[0];
  echo $shop_single_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'shop_single' )[0];

  //echo Image instead of URL
  echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'full');
  echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'medium');
  echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'thumbnail');
  echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'shop_thumbnail');
  echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'shop_catalog');
  echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'shop_single');
}
?>
```